# scrlttr2 enclosure pagebreak

Tags: koma-script, page-breaking, letters, scrlttr2

I am using scrlttr2 to write letters, and in particular add the attachements also provided in the envelope in the `\encl{}` closure.

However, since I add many many entries to the `encl{}` closure, it would need to continue on another page.

Unfortunately, this closure does not do so, leading to the effect, that entries are missing.

As far as I understand it, scrlttr2 is based upon letter and the [documentation of the latter](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/base/letter.pdf) provides the option to allow pagebreaks according to page 13, where it says

> After the \closing you can put arbitrary stuff, which is typeset with zero
> \parindent and no page breaking [..]
> The only thing \ps needs to do is call \startbreaks, which allows page breaking again.
> 219 `\newcommand*\ps{\par\startbreaks`

My MWE looks like

```latex
\documentclass[%
    version=last,%
    parskip=half-,%
    subject=untitled,%
    pagenumber=off,%
    footsepline=off]%
{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \renewcommand*\ps{\par\startbreaks}
    \setkomavar*{enclseparator}{Anlagen}
    \begin{letter}    {%
        Max Mustermann\\
        Vor dem Berg 1\\
        12345 Musterhausen}
        \opening{Dear Mr.,}
        please find attached the discussed documents.
        \closing{Kind regards,}
        \encl{%
            \lipsum[1-1]
            \newpage
            \lipsum[2-2]
        }
    \end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\encl` is not the same as `\ps`. The `\encl` is a `\parbox` in `scrlttr2` and also in `letter`. Therefore page breaks inside `\encl` are not supported. You can only make a page break before `\encl`, either using `\newpage`, `\clearpage`, `\pagebreak` or `\startbreaks` *before* `\encl`.

Comment: BTW: I don't think, that `scrlttr2` is based a lot upon `letter`. It is very, very different. So the documentation of `letter` is not really relevant for `scrlttr2`. For `scrlttr2` you should rely on the chapters about `scrlttr2` and `scrletter` in the KOMA-Script manuals.

Comment: One more note: The definition of `\ps` in `letter.cls` is already `\newcommand*\ps{\par\startbreaks}`. So redefining it to exactly this definition would not change anything. And because `\ps` is not used automatically, you have to explicitly use it, to get an effect. BTW: the `\ps` of `scrlttr2` also contains `\startbreaks`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the responses. Bottom line: It is not possible to strech `\encl{}` across two pages?

Comment: I've already answered this in my first comment.

Answer (score 1):

There are several errors in your premise. Firstly, the `letter` class documentation is not applicable to `scrlttr2`, since `scrlttr2` differs a lot and shares less code with `letter`. So it is recommended to refer to the `scrlttr2` documentation instead. Additionally, if you do not utilize `\ps`, then redefining it would be pointless. Moreover, the original definition of `\ps` in KOMA-Script already includes `\startbreaks`. Redefining `\ps` would not enable `\startbreaks`. It would only eliminate the additional code that KOMA-Script uses and alter the documented behavior of the command.

But the primary error is because of the fact that `\ps` differs from `\encl` in both meaning and implementation.  The `letter` class's version of `\encl` is already defined using `\parbox`. LaTeX utilizes a vertical TeX box, such as `\vbox`, `\vcenter`, or `\vtop`, to create a `\parbox`. This implies that it is impossible to have page breaks inside a `\parbox`. So, the `letter` class does not currently support page breaks within the argument of `\encl`. Testing this is easy:

```latex
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% Note: No longer needed since LaTeX 2018-04-01.
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \renewcommand*\ps{\par\startbreaks}% Note: Does not do anything in the example
    \begin{letter}    {%
        Max Mustermann\\
        Vor dem Berg 1\\
        12345 Musterhausen}
        \opening{Dear Mr.,}
        please find attached the discussed documents.
        \closing{Kind regards,}
        \encl{%
            \lipsum
        }
    \end{letter}
\end{document}
```

And indeed, in this aspect, the `scrltt2` is quite similar to the `letter` class. Class `scrlttr2` prints the `\encl` argument in a `\parbox`. Due to this, it also does not allow for page breaks within the `\encl` argument. The only possible action is to insert `\startbreaks` prior to `\encl` so that page breaks can occur before the argument is printed.

An alternative could be to forego the use of `\encl` for the enclosures and opt for a list instead:

```latex
\documentclass[%
    version=last,%
    parskip=half-,%
    subject=untitled,%
    pagenumber=off,%
    footsepline=off]%
{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% Note: Not needed since LaTeX 2018-04-01.
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \begin{letter}    {%
        Max Mustermann\\
        Vor dem Berg 1\\
        12345 Musterhausen}
        \opening{Dear Mr.,}
        please find attached the discussed documents.
        \closing{Kind regards,}
        \startbreaks
        \begin{labeling}{\enclname:}
          \item[\enclname:] 
            \lipsum[1-1]
            \newpage
            \lipsum[2-2]
        \end{labeling}
    \end{letter}
\end{document}
```

However, I would recommend to not use such long enclosures. And I would also not recommend to use several paragraphs inside the enclosure.

BTW: If just some lines are missing at the first page, an alternative would be to use a letter without page footer using option `firstfoot=false` and enlarge the first page using option `enlargefirstpage`.